# integrating angularjs and backbonejs routing

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js

I have an application where banner is desinged using backbone js which has its own routing mechnism. So its like when you click on banner on top its falls down like curtain and shows all the views in mosaic on dashboard.

My challenege is we are thinking now to implement app with angular js integrating this backbonejs banner.

I have already made things work with angular.bootstrap and all but facing hard time to manage the routing in backbone vs angular.

so problem is if I use angular routing somehow my backbone routing stops functioning. But if I don't use angular routing then backbone routing and angular app works just awesome.

Comment: why don't you use only angularJS routing ? Rewrite the banner to use purely angularJS routing mixing both doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: I know I had the same thought, but the project I am working on is requiring this to avoid new code as backbone code is in production working fine with lots of dollars spent. So they want something in integrated fashion.

That's why I have made this thing working in integrated fashion Angular + Backbone only challenge I am facing is routing.

Comment: A huge challenge you also would face is loading both angular and backbone libraries - angular being 900 Kb(!) in addition to whatever else is in production. I would say don't look for angular plugins to try to be compatible with a backbone system. A benefit of backbone is that it uses the literal DOM as the "V" in its M V V-M architecture (the view) -- therefore any jQuery plugin available would work just fine under a system already using a backbone router. 70% of the web still uses jQuery - and the jQuery plugin network is at least as big as angularJs's. Don't combine such large libraries

Comment: jquery is only about 245kb and probably also used elsewhere on the site, you certainly should use jquery and backbone together, but neither should be paired with angular.